# Adding an API url to cache after button click

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

I have a serviceworker that has been registered. I am using a railway API to fetch some information using getJSON and I am displaying the information using javascript onto the DOM. The API loads and the request is sent only after a button press. The url depends upon input values. I have cached my html,css,js files into cache storage. How do I cache the url for the railways API into cache storage now?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [window.localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).  Here you can store strings (or stringified objects) in a key-value pair dictionary on the client's browser.

Comment: Is there any possibility where I could cache my request to the existing cache storage?

Comment: I believe the `Cache `is meant to be used to store request/responses specifically.  If you're wanting to store the request you're making to the API, you can use [Cache.put](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/put) and then use the [CacheStorage.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/keys) to pull the existing cached values out and then you could find the call that was made before.